# plotting normal vector in 3d

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I have a normal vector that I calculated from the cross product of two vectors [xn,yn,zn] and I have a point[x0,y0,z0] how can I plot the normal in 3d.
I didn't know how to do it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Arrow heads:

```
a = [2 3 5]; % your point [x0,y0,z0]
b = [1 1 0]; % your normal vector 
c = a+b; % end position of normal vector

%quiver3 syntax: quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w)
quiver3(a(1), a(2), a(3), c(1), c(2), c(3));
axis equal;
```

This will hopefully draw a vector from your point into the direction of your normal...with arrow heads. If you want to draw a simple line in 3D you must use plot3:

```
plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,...)
```

The function call should be the same as for quiver3.
:)

**EDIT/ADD:** I just saw that I might have misunderstood what quiver3 does. Actually it seems, that you don't need to substract or add b from a. Because quiver3 just adds a given vector (u, v, w) to a point (x, y, z). Without checking it, I think the call should look like:

```
a = [2 3 5]; % your point [x0,y0,z0]
b = [1 1 0]; % your normal vector 
quiver3(a(1), a(2), a(3), b(1), b(2), b(3));
```

Comment: it draws the vector in the other direction!!

Comment: if I am not wrong, there are two legal normal vecors. If you want it to draw the other vector just substract b from a: c = a-b;

Comment: It didn't work with me but anyway the function and the explanation were sufficient to think about it later on. Thanks

Comment: How could I do it using Plot3?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no Matlab installed, but from the docs it should be the same: plot3(a(1), a(2), a(3), c(1), c(2), c(3));

Comment: I am really sorry that I can't test. Waht about: plot3(a(1):.1:b(1), a(2):.1:b(2), a(3):.1:b(3)) ... or maybe line([a(1), b(1)], [a(2), b(2)], [a(3), b(3)]) ?

Comment: the answer that you edited last time didn't work ( it didn't plot anything)