# Plotting 3D Vector in Matplotlib using a Position and a Quaternion

Tags: python, matplotlib, quaternions

I have the following information:

- A position point (x,y,z)
- An quaternion orientation (w, i, j, k)

I want to plot this as a vector in 3D in Matplotlib. I have seen many questions [(example question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940766/plotting-normal-vector-in-3d) on plotting a 3D vector in Matplotlib. For example, I know I can plot a vector in Matplotlib given two points, a start (x, y, z) and an end (x, y, z) as shown below.

```py
start = [2 3 5];
end = [4 5 5]; 
quiver3(start(1), start(2), start(3), end(1), end(2), end(3));
```

My question is: how can I either convert my position and quaternion into a start and end point so that I can plot it as a vector, or how can I directly plot my position and quaternion?

**Note:** I have the code which plots my position in 3D, I just am unsure how to get the orientation:

```py
ax.set_title("Pos: (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ", " + str(z) + ")")
ax.set_xlim([-5, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
ax.set_zlim([0, 5])
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

[image: Image showing what I have compared to what I need]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a partial solution using [ROS](https://www.ros.org). In [ROS](https://www.ros.org) there is a way to convert a quaternion into a Euler angle using:

```py
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
quaternion = (w,i,j,k)
euler = euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
```

Using this I then could plot the yaw using:

```py
yaw = euler[2]
new_x = sin(yaw)
new_y = cos(yaw)
self.ax.quiver(x, y, z, new_x, new_y, 0, color='b')
```

I think there should be a way to do this in pure Python and there should be a way to get all the angles, however I decided to put this up as a partial solution incase anyone runs into the same problem and no one else answers here.

Comment: One of the issues with going to Euler angles is that it may not reflect the devices rotation properly. For instance {180, 180, 0} is the same as {0,0, 180}  (roll, pitch, yaw)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code I use to draw quivers using start point(x, y, z) and quaternion(a, b, c, d):

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rotate_vector(vector, rotation_matrix):
    return np.dot(rotation_matrix, vector)

def calculate_endpoint(start, a, b, c, d):
    rotation_matrix = R.from_quat([a, b, c, d]).as_matrix()
    unit_vector = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    endpoint = rotate_vector(unit_vector, rotation_matrix)
    return start + endpoint

start_point = np.array([[x, y, z]])
end_point = calculate_endpoint(start_point, a, b, c, d)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.quiver(start_point[0], start_point[1], start_point[2],
                end_point[0], end_point[1], end_point[2],
                length = 1, normalize = True)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

If you want to draw multiple quivers, assuming that you have two variables `start_points` and `end_points` with shape `(number_of_data, 3)` then use this:

```
ax.quiver(start_points[:, 0], start_points[:, 1], start_points[:, 2],
                end_points[:, 0], end_points[:, 1], end_points[:, 2],
                length = 0.1, normalize = True)
```

Depending on your data, you need to tune the `length` variable.